# Can Placing images in a certain drawable folder cause force close?

Tags: android

I have developed an app for Google Play but it is facing force close on certain devices. I have currently placed the images in drawable-mdpi. Can this be a problem as MOTO RAZR HD is one of the devices facing the problem of force close. I have tested on the emulator for HD screen and the app is working fine, But it fails on the actual device.

Can somebody help me in how to place the image resources so that the size of the apk is also not increased.

Comment: can you post the error log here.

Comment: the apk is running fine in emulator but I am getting emails from people who have installed that app regarding force close problem.

Comment: I have used all the small letters and no symbol except underscore '_' because that is also used in the default icon symbol 'ic_launcher'

Comment: posting an error log will enhance clarity.